python pptx bar chart multilevel categories
i am trying to build a table as below using python-pptx.

unfortunately i am failing to correctly pass the categories for the multilevel:
i have tried with sub-categories, i checked the documentation and also found this page
but none of this seems to lead me to a solution. did anyone find out how to build multilevel categories?
thank you
